# How to get the IP address of a host in Elisp?

Tags: networking

I need something like `get-host-by-name` or `getent-hosts` but I can not find any. Do they exist?

Comment: [net-utils](http://web.mit.edu/Emacs/source/emacs/lisp/net/net-utils.el) has `dns-lookup-host`.

Comment: It looks like that `net-utils` also just calls `dig`. That is what I am now doing in my [work-around](https://gist.github.com/ceving/972a0f3d57e69af6d7a37c8fef6e7bb3#file-ansible-inventory-el-L64).

Comment: `dnsResolve` (in `url-ns.el`) tries to call `nslookup`.

Comment: There's also `url-gateway-nslookup-host`, which will chose the utility to call based on your settings (which, I imagine, are influenced by your OS), however, as far as I know, Emacs itself doesn't have its own low-level networking libraries and relies on the system to provide these services. However, if you want to do this on Linux, and you don't want to rely on the presence of any utility, you could still do it by reading / writing to /dev/tcp: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/more-using-bashs-built-devtcp-file-tcpip

Comment: Sorry, I meant /dev/udp (for DNS queries), but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 1):

There is `dns.el`, which was in Gnus for a while but has long since been moved into the more general `net` subdirectory of `lisp`.  This library seems to implement its own resolver.  (It may call `nslookup` only to get your DNS resolver address(es), if you don't set `dns-servers` and `/etc/resolv.conf` cannot be found.)

```
(dns-query "www.google.com")  ; => "216.58.216.196"
```

Comment: Please do not refer to anything in comments, in your answer. Comments can be deleted anytime. Instead, incorporate the material you want from comments, and attribute relevant parts to users who contributed it. Thx.

Comment: @Drew I removed the reference.